# Weird behaviour with zsh PATH

Tags: zsh, osx-yosemite, zshrc

I just encourage a weird problem with zsh today.

My environment is Mac OS X Yosemite, zsh 5.0.5 (x86_64-apple-darwin14.0)

In .zshrc, I have manually set the PATH variable to something like

```
export PATH="$PATH:~/.composer/vendor/bin"
```

Try `echo $PATH` in terminal, the result is as expected (contained `~/.composer/vendor/bin`). Then try executing a binary from `~/.composer/vendor/bin`, It'll always return me "zsh: command not found" error.

Try switching to bash, `echo $PATH` is also as expected, have the same result as zsh shell.
Try executing a binary from `~/.composer/vendor/bin`, no problem found. Seem the PATH var is acting well on the bash shell.

What's wrong with my zsh shell?

Thanks

Comment: Try `$HOME` instead of `~`, and note that "composer" != ".composer"

Comment: Sorry about the "composer" & ".composer", It's a typo, fixing it now

Comment: @WilliamPursell the `$HOME` trick work as expected man. Please make your comment as Answer, I'll marked as solution :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try using `$HOME` instead of `~`.  In many situations, shells do not expand `~` when you expect them to and it is usually better to use `$HOME`.  `~` is really only intended to be a short cut for interactive use.  (The only case I can recall where `~` was preferred was in a .gitalias, where ~ was expanded and variables were not.)

Comment: Big thanks for this your hint which helped [many years later in a way newer macOS version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62251500/). bash resolves tildes in paths correctly, but zsh not. After many hours of researching and trial and error, your post finally helped me, that my custom user scripts in the PATH are again considered for autocompletion and proper execution. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Type `rehash` to pick-up `$PATH` changes.

From the [zsh user guide](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Guide/zshguide03.html):

> The way commands are stored has other consequences. In particular, `zsh`
>   won't look for a new command if it already knows where to find one. If
>   I put a new `ls` command in `/usr/local/bin` in the above example, zsh
>   would continue to use `/bin/ls` (assuming it had already been found). To
>   fix this, there is the command `rehash`, which actually empties the
>   command hash table, so that finding commands starts again from
>   scratch. Users of `csh` may remember having to type `rehash` quite a lot
>   with new commands: it's not so bad in `zsh`, because if no command was
>   already hashed, or the existing one disappeared, `zsh` will
>   automatically scan the path again; furthermore, `zsh` performs a rehash
>   of its own accord if `$path` is altered. So adding a new duplicate
>   command somewhere towards the head of `$path` is the main reason for
>   needing rehash.

**EDIT** However @WilliamPursell could be onto something with his comment:

> note that "composer" != ".composer"

Comment: The `$HOME` trick by @WilliamPursell worked, thanks anyway :)