# "zsh: command not found: dotnet-svcutil" after upgrading to macOS Catalina

Tags: .net-core, zsh, macos-catalina

After upgrading my macOS to 10.15 (Catalina) and [switching from bash to zsh](https://www.theverge.com/2019/6/4/18651872/apple-macos-catalina-zsh-bash-shell-replacement-features), as recommended, I'm trying to start `svcutil` (or any of the other .NET Core tools) from Terminal, but I'm getting the following error message:

> zsh: command not found: dotnet-svcutil

Strange, since its location (`~/.dotnet/tools`, where .NET Core tools are installed by default) is mentioned when checking the path with `echo $PATH`. How can I solve this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29829360/4751173), zsh doesn't support `~` in paths. The path entry for the .NET Core tools is added during installation as a file `/etc/paths.d/dotnet-cli-tools` with path entry `~/.dotnet/tools`. Changing that to `$HOME/.dotnet/tools` or `${HOME}/.dotnet/tools` didn't help, but changing it to the actual path (e.g. `/Users/Glorfindel/.dotnet/tools`) did the trick.

Another option is to reinstall the tool, e.g. with

```
dotnet tool uninstall --global dotnet-svcutil
dotnet tool install --global dotnet-svcutil
```

The installation program will tell you the following, which I haven't tried:

> Tools directory '/Users/Glorfindel/.dotnet/tools' is not currently on the PATH environment variable.
>   If you are using zsh, you can add it to your profile by running the following command:
>
> ```
> cat << \EOF >> ~/.zprofile
> # Add .NET Core SDK tools
> export PATH="$PATH:/Users/Glorfindel/.dotnet/tools"
> EOF
> ```
>
> And run `zsh -l` to make it available for current session.
>
> You can only add it to the current session by running the following command:
>
> ```
> export PATH="$PATH:/Users/Glorfindel/.dotnet/tools"
> ```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, and fixed it by doing the following from Terminal:

copy the contents of  ~/.bash_profile to ~/.zshrc

1. open one terminal window and type `nano ~/.bash_profile`
2. select the code in that file and copy it
3. open another terminal window and type `nano ~/.zshrc`
4. paste and save the file

Re-open VSCode and it should work.  It worked for me!