# zsh can neither find nor execute custom user scripts in ~/bin although they are executable and in the $PATH environment variable

Tags: macos, environment-variables, config, zsh, macos-catalina

**Problem:**

I have recently upgraded from macOS Mojave 10.14.6 to macOS Catalina 10.5.5.

Now that `zsh` is the default shell, I migrated my `.bashrc` to `.zshrc`:

- Aliases work fine.
- But for some unexplainable reason, my custom user scripts in `~/bin/my/` and `~/bin/dev/` are

  - not completed by autocompletion
  - cannot be evoked when typed entirely, I then get `zsh: command not found: myScript.sh`

**Investigation & Troubleshooting:**

- When changing the shell back to bash, everything still works, so data-loss/corruption from the OS update can be ruled out, it must be a configuration issue.
- All my script files have the executable flags.
- The directories they reside in are in the $PATH environment variable.

  - Proof: `echo $PATH` gives `/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Library/Apple/usr/bin:/usr/local/sbin:~/bin/bin:~/bin/my:~/bin/dev:`

**Experiments:**

- I tried setting/appending the $PATH variable with and without the `export` keyword. --> Makes no difference.
- I tried the various possible config files: .zprofile .zshrc --> Makes no difference.
- I hardlinked the bash and the zsh config file and included: `alias test123="echo test123"`

  - This alias works in bash and zsh. So it cannot be a problem in the chain of loading config files.
- I tried different shebang syntaxes  --> Makes no difference. Direct invocation with the full path works all the time anyhow.

Comment: Your path should include `/home/porg/bin/bin`, not `~/bin/bin`. The tilde needs to be expanded by the shell during assignment, because `~` is a shell shortcut not processed by the `exec*` function that uses your `PATH` to locate an executable.

Comment: This problem has had puzzled me about 6 hours. I solved it myself. And shared this as a self answered question, see below. But I included all my original assumptions & troubleshooting in the question, to help people who may wander the same paths in how they phrase their problem into their search engine of choice.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found the solution in [William Pursell's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29829360/199400) concerning [Weird behaviour with zsh PATH](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29820315/):

> Try using $HOME instead of ~. In many situations, shells do not expand ~ when you expect them to and it is usually better to use $HOME.  ~ is really only intended to be a short cut for interactive use.

From then on zsh worked as expected and considered all my custom user scripts in `~/bin/*` after I have replaced all my `~` tilde placeholders with `$HOME` variables in my `$PATH`. — What a great difference a wrong character can make!

Comment: You may have quoted the assignment to `PATH` that included the `~`. Left unquoted, the shell expands it so that the correct path is actually added to your path. For example, `PATH=$PATH:~/bin/bin`, not `PATH="$PATH:~/bin/bin"`.

Comment: Interesting extra info, that tilde expansion differs depending whether included in quotes or not. I append the PATH with a yet another syntax option,  namely with variable expansion (dollar symbol followed by variable name in curly braces).

My config file contains various PATH additions in this syntax:

`export PATH="${PATH}:$HOME/bin/bin"` and  `export PATH="${PATH}:$HOME/bin/my"` and 
export `PATH="${PATH}:$HOME/bin/dev"`.
It works in practise now. But nevertheless maybe it is wrong as in ineffective or having side-effects I may have not considered?

Comment: The quoting isn't particularly interesting; most characters lose their special meaning when quoted. What *is* interesting is that `~` is generally only expanded when it is the first character of a word, but exceptions are made when it immediately follows a `=` or `:` (to allow expansion in assignments and path-like settings). Generally, you can omit quoting of an assignment value, since neither pathname expansion nor glob expansion is an issue (though whitespace must still be quoted, to avoid terminating the assignment early).

Comment: wow - your answer is the only thing that worked, search other similar questions answers and none of them had it - thank you!

Comment: Glad that I could help! Should you not have done it, please upvote. I now set it as the accepted answer, as it worked for myself and now was also confirmed to work for you.